# Layout getting out of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I have 2 views, a `SearchView` and a `SwipeRefreshLayout` that are inside a `ConstraintLayout`.

[image: rendered layout]

I have set the constraints correctly between them but at rendering it shows that the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is getting out of the screen, and when running the app I can't see the last elements as they are "out of the screen".

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/questionsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".fragments.QuestionsFragment">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/items_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: use 0dp for height

Comment: which height are you refering to ? @AtifAbbAsi

Comment: your main parent layout constrain layout.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi it didn't solve the isse .. nothing is shown; I guess because height is 0 and everything is hidden :/

Comment: try running app.it will auto adjust layout.

Comment: try use the **NestedScrollView** Following the Demo